# Microservice, Socket IO and Kafka architecture question

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, socket.io, architecture

I have an application with 4 microservices, all of which emit events to the client via socketio.
Currently the client creates a socket io client connection to each service

```
const apiSocket = new io(gateway, resolveOptions("/api"));
const chatSocket = new io(gateway, resolveOptions("/chat"));
const otherServiceSocket = new io(gateway, resolveOptions("/example"));
const ThatOtherServiceSocket = new io(gateway, resolveOptions("/example2"));
```

and then they are imported into the various components that need them. The problem I'm seeing with this is that I'm having to write a lot of duplicate code and subscribe sockets to particular channels repeatedly.

Recently I've been learning kafka, and the following architecture occured to me, and I wanted to consult S.O to be sure whether it makes sense, and If there are any cons to doing so:

[image]

Creating a single web socket service which handles all web socket events and connections (or several and load balancing with nginx)

then publishing events to kafka that the relevant services will consume. If a service needs to send an event to the client to trigger a notification or something like that, it will publish an event to kafka which the web socket service will consume and then emit to the client.

Does this architecture make sense. Are there any drawbacks to doing this?

Here's a video of me explaining the issue:
https://www.loom.com/share/57cf8a542f434a85ab638c4b2ffd9999

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are effectively making a [BFF pattern](https://medium.com/zinklar-tech/backend-for-frontend-bff-pattern-5e8810779d9f) with your single web-socket service.  There is nothing wrong with it, this pattern is used all the time to simplify complex back-end service architectures (especially when people over-decompose their microservices).

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about the technical term for what I was creating. My knowledge of software patterns is quite limited. Thank you for the response.